# function and defered jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i'm very confused on this argument: I know that in javascript function executes in an
asyncronous way sometimes and here is my problem. i have a function called

```
function createPopupHour()
```

this function creates an html select element and it doesn't return nothing. I call this function in a $.AJAX request in the success part of the request.

```
$.ajax({
            url:"responseregistrodocente.php",
            data:{
                operazione:'caricaAssenza',
                idAssenza:id_array[3],
                codiceFiscale: id_array[0],
                data:id_array[1],
                tipo:id_array[2]
                },
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function (jsonObject) {
            createPopupHourSelect()
            //other code
            }); 

            },
            error: function(error){
                //XMLREQQUESTOBJECT
                alert(error.responseText);
                location.reload();
            },
            cache:false,
            ifModified:false
        });
```

the problem is that when i call the function the other code doesn't attent that my function end. i know that in jquery there is the "deferred Object",maybe i need that my function create a deferred object, and return it to the code. but how is the sintax:? or is there another more easy and dry solution???

is correct something like this?

```
function createPopupHour select(){ //staff to do
return $.deferred();//it's in pending state
}
```

and $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
                url:"responseregistrodocente.php",
                data:{
                    operazione:'caricaAssenza',
                    idAssenza:id_array[3],
                    codiceFiscale: id_array[0],
                    data:id_array[1],
                    tipo:id_array[2]
                    },
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"json",
                success: function (jsonObject) {
                var defered=createPopupHourSelect()
                defered.then(function{//other code])
                        defered.resolve();
                }); 

                },
                error: function(error){
                    //XMLREQQUESTOBJECT
                    alert(error.responseText);
                    location.reload();
                },
                cache:false,
                ifModified:false
            });
```

Comment: What do you mean by " the other code doesn't attent that my function end" ?

Comment: Using asynchronous code is not needed for normal program flow, when the function returns the code after the call will execute. If the other code doesn't run, then it's probably because your code crashed, either when calling the function, or inside the function. Check the error console for any Javascript error messages.

Comment: i mean that the code MUST runs before the function beacuse i can't for example change css style of a button than i create in the function because when the css is modified the button doesn't exist.

Comment: `$.ajax` returns a deferred promise() (jQuery 1.5 or above). In other words, you can simply make the function `return $.ajax({ /*...*/ });` and check `yourFunction().done()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `other code` needs to reside in a callback function that will be executed when popup thing is done, just like the popup startup code is executed when the ajax is done. You can either use a primitive callback, or use the more powerful [promise](http://promisesaplus.com/) pattern.

The syntax for [jQuery `Deferred` objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) is

```
function …() {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    // start asynchronous task
         // when the task is done (in the future), call
         def.resolve(…); // optionally with results
    // and right now do
    return def.promise();
}
```

---

Since `$.ajax` does return a promise as well, you can use chaining via [`.then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) (assuming `createPopUpHourSelect` is in the above pattern):

```
$.ajax({
    url:"responseregistrodocente.php",
    data:{…},
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    cache:false,
    ifModified:false
})
.fail(function(error){
    alert(error.responseText);
    location.reload();
})
.then(createPopupHourSelect) // gets passed the parsed JSON
.then(function(result) { // gets passed the resolve arguments from the popup
    // other code
});
```

If you need the ajax response in the other code as well and don't want to pass it through the popup function, use

```
.then(function(json) {
    return createPopupHourSelect(…)
    .then(function(popupResults) {
         // other code
    });
}) /* returns a promise that resolves with result of other code
.then(…) */
```